# MP3 vs CAF: Does it matter which audio format is used for sound effects in an iPhone game?

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, cordova, mp3

We're building an iPhone game using PhoneGap.

iOS devices support many audio formats, and we are thinking about using .mp3 or .caf files for the sound effects.

Does it matter which audio format is used? What are the differences between using one versus another?

Answer (score 1):

CAF for Sound Effects

MP3 for soundtracks (mp3 files can't be loop, it has a small pause in between)

Comment: can you explain why? we're using mp3 for sound effects now, and it seems to work okay ... but not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: Got this advice from raywenderlich a while back. -->
But the most important thing to know here is that usually you’ll just want to use CAF, because it can contain any encoding supported on the iPhone, and it is the preferred file format on the iPhone. http://www.raywenderlich.com/204/audio-tutorial-for-ios-file-and-data-formats